# Reading Excel file and find the first empty cell using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have to create a Desktop Application.
I use Visual studio 2015 and Excel
I have to :
-open an excel file
-find the first empty row
-write new data in that row
-save that file ( at the moment i can create just a new file. I don't know how to update ad save the same I open)
It works until I open the file..
Thank you!
This is the function I wrote to open the file:

```
Public Function OpenExcel(filename As String) As Object
        Dim retval As Object = Nothing
        Try
            Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
            Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
            excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
            excel.Visible = False
            wb.Activate()
            ws = wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
            ws = excel.ActiveSheet
            retval = ws.Cells(1, 1).value

        Catch ex As exception

        End Try
    End Function
```

**And this is the first part of my code**

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim dialogo As OpenFileDialog
        dialogo = New OpenFileDialog()
        dialogo.ShowDialog()
        Dim ds As Object = f.OpenExcel(dialogo.FileName)

 Dim oExcel As Object
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oSheet1 As Object

        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
        oSheet1 = oBook.Worksheets(1)

        oBook = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook

        Dim UR As Integer = 0
        UR = oSheet1.Range("A" & oSheet1.Rows.Count).End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        For rr = 1 To UR
            If oSheet1.Range("A" & rr).Value = ("") Then
                oSheet1.Range("A" & rr).value = "text1"
            Else
                MsgBox("box pieno")
            End If
        Next rr

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        oBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\an\Desktop\New" & ".xlsx")
        oBook.Close()
        oBook = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You *almost* had it.

Your function already opens the file; just change it to return the workbook.

```
Public Function OpenExcel(ByVal filename As String) As Object
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    excel.Visible = False
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=False)
    excel.Visible = False
    Return wb
End Function
```

(btw, is not really a good idea to have your exception handling here, unless you're returning a "status" value or a default file. Let the caller handle the exceptions)

...then have the rest of your code change and save the already opened book

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dialogo As OpenFileDialog
    dialogo = New OpenFileDialog()
    dialogo.ShowDialog()
    Dim oBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet1 As Object

    Try
        oBook = OpenExcel(dialogo.FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle your exception here
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    oSheet1 = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim UR As Integer = 0
    UR = oSheet1.Range("A" & oSheet1.Rows.Count).End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    For rr = 1 To UR
        If oSheet1.Range("A" & rr).Value Is Nothing OrElse oSheet1.Range("A" & rr).Value.ToString() = ("") Then
            oSheet1.Range("A" & rr).value = "text1"
        End If
    Next rr

    Dim excel = oBook.Application

    oBook.Save()
    oBook.Close()
    excel.Quit() 'This is important: as your application is not visible, it would stay on memory until reboot or shutdown if you don't close it here
    oBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It works and I can write in the next cell. But there is a problem: Until I select the file, if I check the background processes opened in my pc, I don't have any Excel. I select the file I want to open and -the window blocked itself -in the background processes, excel appears Now if I close the process and I push again the open button It works. I don't understand what happen